# Can't find bug in code snippet

Tags: javascript, debugging

There is a bug in my code and I can't work out what it is. Please help!

```
var curComment='<p><span class="cmtname" '+cname
+':'+'</span>'+ctext+'</p>';
$('#cmtlist').empty();
$('#cmtlist').append(curComment);
```

Comment: What's the bug?

Comment: Check console log

Comment: Your span tag is not closed in first line.

Comment: and there is a `cname` which is who knows what that also has a colon appended to it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a closing **>** on your **span** tag, but it is super hard to see if you jam everything together like that.  You might want to consider adding in some space in your code.

```js
var cname = "myCName";
var ctext = "myCText";
var curComment = '<p><span class="cmtname">' + cname + ':' + '</span>' + ctext + '</p>';

$('#cmtlist').empty();
$('#cmtlist').append(curComment);
```

```css
.cmtname { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="cmtlist"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```